# How to pass generic provider to child?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to create a universal alert that I will use several times in my app.

```
class SelectIconAlertDialogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectIconAlertDialogWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<IncomeViewModel>(context, listen: true).state;

    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
      ),
```

Problem is that I can not figure out how to pass type of parent ChangeNotifier

```
                  showDialog<String>(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) =>
                        ChangeNotifierProvider<IncomeViewModel>.value(
                      value: view,
                      child: const SelectIconAlertDialogWidget(),
                    ),
                  );
```

I have a lot of ViewModels that will use this alert so dont want to repeat this code and write generic Alert that I can use with any ViewModel. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some abstract class with methods or fields you want to have for all your view models you use for that dialog

```
abstract class AbstractViewModel{
  void doStuff();
}
```

Implement this class for your view models

```
class MyViewModel1 implements AbstractViewModel{
   @override
   void doStuff (){ print("from MyViewModel1");}
}
```

Add type parameter for your dialog class

```
 class SelectIconAlertDialogWidget<T extends AbstractViewModel> extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectIconAlertDialogWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // and you can use generic type T like this:
    final model = Provider.of<T>(context, listen: true);
    model.doStuff();

    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
      ),
```

And call it passing type parameter `SelectIconAlertDialogWidget<MyViewModel1>()`

```
showDialog<String>(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) =>
                        ChangeNotifierProvider<MyViewModel1>.value(
                      value: view,
                      child: const SelectIconAlertDialogWidget<MyViewModel1>(),
                    ),
                  );
```

On build method of your dialog widget it will print "from MyViewModel1". Hope you got the concept of abstraction.

Comment: Hello.Tried your solution but get the following issue **The getter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'T'.
Try importing the library that defines 'state', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'state'**

Comment: `final model = Provider.of<T>(context, listen: true).state;`

**'state' isn't defined for the type 'T'**
I can not understand how I can access fields of ViewModel and can't call functions if use your approach :( @Kerim

Comment: Updated the answer where T extends  IncomeViewModel

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: How can I reuse this widget if I want to extend it from AccountViewModel, not IncomeViewModel?

Comment: I want to make this alert generic so that I can use it with any ViewModel

Comment: Just make an abstract class and implement it by AccountViewModel and IncomeViewModel so they will have common methods and fields. See my updated answer.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and accept it if it fits your use-case